# "explanations on topics related to mathematics" or "explanations of topics related to mathematics"

Tags: prepositions, expressions, mathematics

Which sentence is the most appropriate ?

#1 - Short explanations on topics related to mathematics

#2 - Short explanations of topics related to mathematics

#3 - Short explanations on topics related with mathematics

#4 - Short explanations of topics related with mathematics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"related with" doesn't work as well as "related to".

Apart from that, the phrase *explanations **of** topics* sounds as if the topic is explained completely, while *explanations **on** topics* sounds more like partial explanations.